# Windows - How to allow clients to access their files across all machines connected to AD domain?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, files

I have a Windows Server 2008 server and have Windows 7 client machines. Is it is possible for all clients to log in to their accounts on any computer in the network and be able to access their files/settings/programs from anywhere on the network?

Basically, I am asking if it is possible to have all the devices sync across the network automatically into the user profile folders on all of the clients.

Is this possible?

Comment: Roaming Profiles and Folder Redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think I know what you're asking and I'll tell you but first I'm going to tell you a better method.

First, each user that will be using network resources must have an account set up on the Active Directory using the built in Users and Computers tool. I would not recommend using shared accounts.

All workstations must be added to the domain. this can be done in the same location you would change the computer name at. Usually control panel > system.

On your file storage server, set up a folder for each user to be used as their personal network storage, giving security permissions on each folder to it's intended user. Then, on each users machine, with them logged into the domain under their domain account, map a network drive using the file path for the users personal network storage folder, (ie, \\fileserver\alluserfolders\specificuserfolder, or whatever your filepath is)

However if you want resources on a specific users machines to be available to the network you first must make that machine discover-able on the network, then you can select the specific resource you want to share and then share it to the network from its properties > sharing tab. Doing this on every machine is terribly inefficient and a bad bad bad idea. Do not do it this way. Do it using the method I outlined in the paragraphs above this one.

In short, you *can* do it via network sharing from each machine (which I *think* is what you were asking about.) But you should never ever do it unless you like crying a lot.

If I were you I would research how to configure effective AD Domains as this is a fairly novice level question. [Here](https://support.cloudshare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200701095-How-to-setup-and-configure-a-Domain-Controller-on-Windows-Server-2008-R2) is an ok guide on setting up a domain controller in order to start configuring domain user accounts.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. This method seems to be good, except for one question I have: does this mean that if the clients were to click their user profile (in the Start menu for example), they could access their files that they could access anywhere else on the the network?

Comment: @CBI They will be able to access any file that they have in their mapped network drive from any PC attached to the domain network. They would just need to save all their files to their network share as opposed to on their desktop. This might require some end-user training if this isn't how they are used to doing things. (as many people are used to just saving every single file they make directly on their desktop "because it's easier")

Answer (score 0):

The features you are looking for are Roaming Profiles and Folder Redirection. It is relatively trivial to setup but in my experience it can easily be done poorly and cause more problems than it solves. You also need to be aware that it can represent a SIGNIFICANT impact to your network and storage performance during busy logon/logoff times(typically your 9am and 5pm times). I recommend looking into the Best Practice guides and reading some pros/cons before going down this road.

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely look into Roaming Profiles and Folder Redirection. I appreciate the help.